# RelativeLayout: coordinates value for pos()

Tags: kivy

I modified kivy example and I do not understand to result. I placed button to top left screen corner by using *pos()*.  I assumed using coordinates *(0,240)* but I have to use *(0, 480)*. Please, cann you explain me it?

```
class Pos_Size_App(App):

    def build(self):

        # A Relative Layout with a size of (300, 300) is created
        rl = RelativeLayout(size =(300, 300))

        b1 = Button(size_hint =(.2, .2),
                    pos =(0,480),
                    text ="pos_hint")

        # adding button to widget
        rl.add_widget(b1)

        return rl
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem solution:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
dim_x = 300
dim_y = 300

Window.size = (dim_x, dim_y)
root = RelativeLayout(size =(dim_x, dim_y))
    . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `RelativeLayout` `size` is ignored. The default `size_hint` of `(1,1)` will over-ride the specified `size`. So to get your `size` to actually be `(300,300)` you must add `size_hint=(None, None)`:

```
rl = RelativeLayout(size_hint=(None, None), size =(300, 300))
```